# Does including Contract.Assert have any effect on execution?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have seen code which includes `Contract.Assert` like,

```
Contract.Assert(t != null);
```

Will using `Contract.Assert` have a negative impact on my production code?

Comment: hmm it depends.. ofcource it will have an impact on performance, but I belive you can *turn off* the contracts - so that they will *not* be executed. this is handy for code that is ready for production :)

Comment: If by "impact on performance" you mean returning from the function immediately should the assert succeed. It's unlikely that takes longer than the actual logic of the function. And ideally you would only ship code to production that's actually correct, i.e. the asserts do not fail.

Comment: i like asserts, even though they mess up the code a bit, they save lots of time writing already written Unit Tesing Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) on page 11, they're only included in your assembly when the `DEBUG` symbol is defined (which, of course, includes Debug builds, but not Release builds (by default)).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the runtime benefits of `Contract.Assert`, you can also consider the alternative of using `Contract.Assume` ([Manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) section 2.5 page 11) when making calls to legacy code which does not have contracts defined, and if you like having the static warning level cranked up on high (e.g. static checking level `more warnings` or `all warnings` - level 3+ - and `Show Assumptions` turned on).

`Contract.Assume` gives you the same *run time* benefits as `Contract.Assert`, but also suppresses static checks which can't be proven because of the legacy assembly.

e.g. in the below code, with static checking enabled and warnings set to level 3 gives the `warning : CodeContracts: requires unproven: someString != null` when checking the contracts of `MethodDoesNotAllowNull`

```
 var aString = Legacy.MethodWithNoContract();
 MethodDoesNotAllowNull(aString); 

  private void MethodDoesNotAllowNull(string someString)
  {
     Contract.Requires(someString != null);
  }
```

With Legacy Assembly code:

```
  public static string MethodWithNoContract()
  {
     return "I'm not really null :)";
  }
```

`Assume` suppresses the warning (but gives the run time Assert benefit in debug builds):

```
 var aString = LegacyAssembly.LegacyMethodWithNoContract();
 Contract.Assume(aString != null);
 MethodDoesNotAllowNull(aString);
```

This way, you still get the `empirical` runtime benefit of the `Contract.Assert` in debug builds.

Answer (score -1):

As for good practices it is better to have a set of good unit tests. Then code contracts are not that necessary. They may be helpful, but are less important.